Is there a way to specify Typescript events based on obsidian element creation?
After typing some markdown and pressing enter, obsidian converts the text into a formatted form. I am trying to build a plugin to change the color of callout elements based on the name. I've got it working, but only when the extension is first installed. What I want is for it to recalculate every time a callout is edited or created, or when the user switches between reading view and editing mode.
This is what my javascript on my plugin looks like
export default class MyPlugin extends Plugin {
    settings: MyPluginSettings;
    async onload() {
        await this.loadSettings();
        await this.ConvertColor();
    }

    onunload() {
    }

    async loadSettings() {
        this.settings = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_SETTINGS, await this.loadData());
    }


    async ConvertColor() {
             // ...code for converting color
        });
    }
}


and this is an example of the markdown:
> [!192,255,46] Test
> Testing

which results in:

Instead of onload, I would like to find some way to run ConvertColor() whenever the markdown text is converted by obsidian. but I don't know what event that would be (if it exists).
Any ideas?

That's a sweet plugin idea. If you're still working on this, you could try writing a Markdown post processor which should run every time your file changes.

You could also try using pure CSS, since you can style any callout type using its data-callout attribute. For example, a [!green] callout could be selected using .callout[data-callout="green"]. You'd have to write your own list of recognized color names, but your code would be a lot simpler.
